# SQL Server 2000 - DVWA - including '-' character

Tags: sql, sql-server, get, sql-server-2000, sql-injection

I am working with Damn Vulnerable Web App against a Microsoft SQL Server. My question is actually quite straight forward, but can be mis-interpreted quite easily. Basically. This is my query:

```
+AND+1=convert(int,
    (select+
        top+1+
        user+
    from+
        TBL-Users
    )
)--
```

Now my question is simple. This is the query to extract data from the columns. How do I craft it so that it allows me to extract data from this column? Because apparently, it does not like that I am using the '-' character in this query (but that's the table name).

According to this error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Line 1: Incorrect
>   syntax near '-'.

How can I work around this, and get the data from the column assuming that the '-' character is in the table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL-Server you can basically use most of the reserved words and special characters inside []:

```
select *  from [TBL-Users]
```

Comment: Big THANK-YOU to you man!

Also, one more thing. Is it possible to select all the data from that certain column, or atleast select the next piece of data from the column? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: I didn't get what you exactly mean. Maybe this: `select column_name from [tbl-users]`?

Comment: Though, when I write that like this:

+AND+1=convert(int,(select+user+from+[tbl-users]))--
  
I get this error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Firstly remove those extra `+` characters from your query. Then `select user from [tbl-users]` is returning more than one record. If you execute the query you can see the result set. `convert` method needs a single value as its second param which means you should limit your query to sth like: `select user from [tbl-users] WHERE id=1`

Comment: You can do following as well, I don't really know what is your requirement:
`set @my_var = (SELECT top 1 convert(int, user) FROM [tbl-users])`